Can't access to my model User from Laravel Breeze user with Livewire 3 or Alpine
I am using Laravel 11 (With laravel Breeze) and Livewire 3.
I have a livewire component to edit users. This component shows a Edit/Show page with the possibility of modify your user. The problem here is that Livewire is not detecting my user model and the data binding not working. I have no idea how to debug this.
This is my livewire component. Represents a "user profile". We mount a user model and a flag to determine when the userprofile is en "show" or "edit" mode. This allows my component view show inputs or directly plain text (non-modifiable)
<?php
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;

class UserProfile extends Component
{
    public User $usuario; 
    public bool $isEditing = false;

    protected $queryString = [
        'isEditing',
    ];

    public function mount(int $userId, bool $isEditing = false)
    {
        $this->usuario = User::findOrFail($userId); 
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        $this->isEditing = true;
    }

    public function cancel()
    {
        $this->isEditing = false;
        $this->usuario->refresh();
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $this->usuario->save();
        $this->isEditing = false;
        session()->flash('success', 'User updated successfully!');
    }

}

The component view is this. The toogle between edit-show work great, and the {{$usuario->name}} variable works showing the name of the user.
<div>
    
    @if (session()->has('message'))
        <div class="mb-4 bg-green-100 text-green-800 px-4 py-2 rounded">
            {{ session('message') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    @if ($isEditing)
    <div class="mb-6">
        <h2 class="text-lg font-semibold text-red-500 dark:text-gray-100">
            {{ __('_UserProfile.TitleEdit') }}
        </h2>
    </div>
    @endif

    <div class="space-y-4">

        <!-- Nombre -->
        <div>
            <label class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300">{{ __('_UserManagement.Name') }}</label>
            @if ($isEditing)
            {{$usuario->name}}
                <input type="text" 
                    wire:model.defer="usuario.name"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                @error('usuario.name') <span class="text-red-600 text-sm">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            @else
                <p class="mt-1 text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200">{{ $usuario->name }}</p>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Botones -->
    <div class="mt-6 flex space-x-2">
        @if ($isEditing)
            <button wire:click="save" class="px-4 py-2 bg-blue-600 text-white text-sm rounded hover:bg-blue-700">
                {{ __('_Save') }}
            </button>
            <button wire:click="cancel" class="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-600 text-white text-sm rounded hover:bg-gray-700">
                {{ __('_Cancel') }}
            </button>
        @else
            <button wire:click="edit" class="px-4 py-2 bg-indigo-600 text-white text-sm rounded hover:bg-indigo-700">
                {{ __('_Edit') }}
            </button>
            <a href="{{ route('users.index') }}" class="px-4 py-2 bg-red-600 text-white text-sm rounded hover:bg-gray-700">
                {{ __('_Back') }}
            </a>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>

Anyway, I see the input empty (It should be filled with the value without the needed of use the value property of the input). When I type some text in the input, I see this error message in the console for each letter I type:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'name')
    at dataSet (livewire.js?id=def850b5:379:26)
    at dataSet (livewire.js?id=def850b5:386:5)
    at Object.set (livewire.js?id=def850b5:9899:13)
    at setValue (livewire.js?id=def850b5:3357:16)
    at livewire.js?id=def850b5:3374:7
    at HTMLInputElement.handler4 (livewire.js?id=def850b5:3180:27)

In the livewire docs, I read that livewire supports Eloquent Models, and my User object is a subclass of an Eloquent Model (From lavarel Breeze).
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/properties#common-php-types
I tried checking my usuario model object from Alpine but I get this error:
Alpine Expression Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

Expression: "$wire.usuario.name"

 <h2 x-text=​"$wire.usuario.name">​</h2>​
handleError @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:1120
(anonymous) @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:1193
Promise.catch
(anonymous) @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:1193
tryCatch @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:1113
(anonymous) @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:3493
reactiveEffect @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:2428
effect2 @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:2403
effect @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:761
wrappedEffect @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:777
(anonymous) @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:3492
flushHandlers @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:1278
stopDeferring @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:1283
deferHandlingDirectives @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:1286
initTree @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:1476
(anonymous) @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:1425
start @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:1424
start2 @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:8773
(anonymous) @ livewire.js?id=def850b5:10080

I tried adding/deleting explicit type in the mount withtout changes.
I tried printting directly the user with blade template syntax (this is working)
I tried enabling defer on my model or disabling to check if the problem was caused for the "wire" attribute.
